# Representing a tree as a union of several paths

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification

Let $T$ be a tree with $l$ leaves. Let $k$ be a positive integer such that $2k\geq l$. Show that there exist $k$ paths such that:

1. $P_1\cup\ldots\cup P_k = T$, that is, $T$ can be partitioned into $k$ paths
2. $V(P_i)\cap V(P_j)\neq\varnothing$ for all $i,j$, that is, every path has at least one vertex in common with every other path.

I almost have the solution but it does not feel very clean, and is maybe just wrong:

Select $k$ maximal paths such that every leaf in $T$ belongs to a path. We know this is possible since every path can contain up to $2$ leaves, and we were given that $2k \geq l$. I then argue that by following this process both properties hold.

Property 2: Suppose we follow this process and end up with paths $Q,R$ such that $Q \cap R = \varnothing$. Then there exists a path J  that joins an internal vertex of Q to an internal vertex of R. If this is the case then we can select new paths $Q', R'$ such that $Q\cup R\cup J\subseteq R'\cup Q'$. Then by replacing $Q$ and $R$ with $Q'$ and $R'$, property 2 holds.

Property 1: Suppose for contradiction that we followed this process and ended up with $k$ paths that are not a partition of $T$. Then there exists some $e \in E(T)$ such that $e \notin P_1 \cup\ldots\cup P_k$. Since $T$ is a tree, this would imply that our path partitioning has split the tree into two connected components, $T_1, T_2$. Then there are no paths which have one end in one component and one end in the other, therefore paths in $T_1$ share no vertices with paths in $T_2$, contradicting property 2.

This just feels a little bit dirty to me and I'm not totally convinced that it is permissible to "prove" property 1 in this way.

Comment: "Let $m$ be a positive integer such that $2k \ge j$": $m$ is a typo for $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the choice of $k$ paths in your reasoning is not very clear, so the justification for property 2 doesn't look very good. This phrase "Select $k$ maximal paths" is not clear what it means. I suggest a couple of clarifications of your reasoning.

1. **Select $k$ paths.**
   Let the set $M=\{P_1,\ldots,P_k\}$ of paths be chosen such that the following conditions are satisfied:
   $(i)$ Each path of $M$ connects a pair of leaves.
   $(ii)$ Each leaf is the end of one of the paths of $M$.
   $(iii)$ The sum of the lengths of all paths of the set $M$ with properties $(i)$ and $(ii)$ is maximal.
   Since by condition $k\geq l/2$ there exists at least one set $M$ with properties $(i)$ and $(ii)$.
2. **Property 2**
   for $M$ is now proved exactly as you do, but the proof of this property should end like this:
   $$
   \operatorname{length}(P')+\operatorname{length}(Q')\geq
   \operatorname{length}(P)+\operatorname{length}(Q)+\operatorname{length}(J)>\\
   $$
   $$
   \operatorname{length}(P)+\operatorname{length}(Q).
   $$
   We get a contradiction with the choice of $M$.
3. **Property 1.**
   The proof you propose is very good.
   The only thing to clarify is that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are components of the graph $T-e$.